# Inserting a comment in the pdf report of the execution of a matlab.unittest.TestCase function

Tags: matlab, pdf, testing, report, simulink

I have not been able to find the solution to this anywhere: I have a Testcase class, containing several functions that relate to all the individual tests I wish to perform on a Simulink model. The results of each individual test is logged accordingly in a pdf obtained using a different script.
What I wish to do is add a comment before the execution of each individual function in the test case. I'll provide a picture of both the current execution of our code, as well as what I wish to do:
My code for the Testcase class:

```
classdef tests_HIL_ADF < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods(Test)
        function SC001_SN001_SN002(testCase)
            global in_test;
            load('SC001_SN001_SN002_in.mat');
            load('SC001_SN001_SN002_out.mat');
            simulation_out = sim('my_open_simulink_model',400);
            sim_out = struct(simulation_out);
            oracle = struct(OUT_Test);
            time = (1:1:length(oracle.Data.Q_Valid));
            import matlab.unittest.diagnostics.FigureDiagnostic
            f = figure;
            plot(time, sim_out.Data.Q_Valid, time, oracle.Data.Q_Valid); 
            grid on
            legend("Simulation Output", "Oracle");
            testCase.verifyEqual(uint8(sim_out.Data.Q_Valid(time)), ...
                uint8(oracle.Data.Q_Valid), 'RelTol', 0.1, "Q_Valid");
            close(f);
            f = figure;
            plot(time, sim_out.Data.Train_Info_Q_Valid(time), time, ...
                oracle.Data.Train_Info_Q_Valid); grid on
            legend("Simulation Output", "Oracle");
            testCase.verifyEqual(uint8(sim_out.Data.Train_Info_Q_Valid(time)), ...
                uint8(oracle.Data.Train_Info_Q_Valid),'AbsTol',1, "Train_Info_Q_Valid");
            close(f);
        end
        % more functions with different variables go here
    end
end
```

The code used to run the script and generate the PDF file:

```
---

---

import matlab.unittest.TestRunner
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite
import matlab.unittest.plugins.TestReportPlugin
import matlab.unittest.plugins.CodeCoveragePlugin
import matlab.unittest.plugins.codecoverage.CoverageReport
global in_test;
suite = TestSuite.fromFile('tests_HIL_ADF.m');
runner = TestRunner.withTextOutput;
pdfFile = strcat('tests_HIL_ADF.pdf');
plugin = TestReportPlugin.producingPDF(pdfFile,'LoggingLevel', 4);
runner.addPlugin(plugin);
result = runner.run(suite)
```

[Its normal output, lacking comments.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxcZV.png)

[What I WISH to see in the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXqv3.png)

Any idea how I can get that "Comments" section to print out for each function in the resulting PDF? Even if it's weird workarounds, I'm okay either way.